# solr oracle DIH outofmemory

Tags: oracle, solr

I use solr4.5.Try to import seven million rows data into solr.
The database is Oracle.The db-data-config.xml is:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl2" batchSize="700" user="solrdata" password="solrdata" /> 
  <document> 
    <entity name="claim" query="select * from TD_PERFORMANC_STATUS_MONITOR"> 
    </entity> 
  </document> 
</dataConfig>
```

I had to try set batchSize,but failed.I don't know why the "batchSize" not work.Maybe I used a wrong xml. By the way, I start solr use command"java -jar start.jar".

I found this page:http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/DIH-import-quot-out-of-memory-quot-problem-batchSize-and-autoCommit-not-working-td528211.html

and placed my jdbc driver to D:\solr-4.5.0\example\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib but still didn't work.
Please tell me how to index my data.
Thank you.

Comment: This does not look like a valid query - `select from TD_PERFORMANC_STATUS_MONITOR`. What error are you getting?

Comment: I am sorry I made a misstake.Thank you for you point.

Comment: As you have no column mappings in your `<entity>`, is this really the configuration you are using?

Comment: I have `<dynamicField name="*"   type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>`in my schema.xml. Because this table is all string type.